# Che cos'è una "macchina pubblica"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> – Ultimamente veniva troppo spesso, e quasi sempre di notte. A me francamente quelle ore non piacevano. Arrivava con la **macchina pubblica**. Si ricorda quella che posteggiava sempre davanti al municipio? Quella bella macchina nera, poi con quel ridicolo impianto a gasogeno?
>         – Sí.

Qualcuno di voi mi sa spiegare cos'è una "macchina pubblica". Ho cercato alla voce "macchina" e "pubblico" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente a riguardo.

Comment: Da quel che so, per auto pubblica o auto di piazza si intende di solito un taxi.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Infatti, alla [voce "tassì" del dizionario di sinonimi e contrari Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tassi_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)) appare: (*non com.*) auto pubblica, (*disus.*) vettura di piazza. Tuttavia, non so se ci fossero taxi ad Alba nei primi anni quaranta (durante la guerra) nel senso di macchina fornita di tassametro.

Comment: Cioè, potrebbe trattarsi di una macchina con autista a noleggio (e non necessariamente con tassametro)?

Comment: Non saprei... che si tratti di persone munite di automobile, che si mettono a disposizione per accompagnare le persone (a noleggio come dici tu)? Forse. 
In ogni caso ho letto qui: http://www.autonoleggioconautista.taxi/Taxi_a_Milano_foto_storiche.php che il tassametro esisteva già dagli anni '20 se non prima

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  D'accordo, ma non penso che Milano sia comparabile ad Alba.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Se vuoi puoi scrivere una risposta usando la [voce "tassì" del dizionario di sinonimi e contrari Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tassi_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)) (non è veramente importante se la macchina avesse o meno il tassametro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per "auto pubblica" o "auto di piazza" si intende un taxi; sono espressioni non molto utilizzate o desuete: vedi la [voce "tassì" sul dizionario di sinonimi e contrari Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tassi_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)).